# Universal link user experience?

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have an app that show photos, and I have a link for a specific photo **inside** the app that I would like to send a friend. This link has no webpage, only a link for a place inside the app.

My friend has an iPhone but don't have the app.

Is there an option (that works seamlessly) that he will click the link, will be asked to download the app, and will be taken right away to the photo page in the app without any hassle ?

Is there an example I can try online for other companies ?

`Universal Link` seems to fit, but I am not sure from the keynote if my use case is possible :
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/509/

Comment: anyone have a solution 
?